# instance variable difference (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables

I have 2 questions about the solutions below.

Below is my answer (Solution 1) for this question of leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/distribute-coins-in-binary-tree/

```
# Solution 1:
class Solution:
    def distributeCoins(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        self.ans = 0

        def dfs(node):
            if not node:
                return 0

            L, R = dfs(node.left), dfs(node.right)
            self.ans += abs(L) + abs(R)
            return node.val + L + R - 1

        dfs(root)
        return self.ans
```

**Quesion1** I was wondering why below does not work. What is the difference between the variable `ans` of Solution 1 and Solution 2?

```
# Solution 2:
class Solution:
    def distributeCoins(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        ans = 0  
        self.dfs(root, ans)
        return ans
    
    def dfs(self, node, ans):
        if not node:
            return 0

        L, R = self.dfs(node.left, ans), self.dfs(node.right, ans)
        ans += abs(L) + abs(R)

        return node.val + L + R - 1
```

Because changes on `grid` variable below (Solution 3) is accumulated and affects all each recursions, I thought it would also be the case for Solution 2.

**Question2** What is the difference between `ans` of Solution 2 and `grid` of Solution 3 which makes the differences due to recursion not accumulate?
(Below is solution for https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/)

```
# Solution 3:
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        if not grid:
            return 0

        count = 0
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                if grid[i][j] == '1':
                    self.dfs(i, j, grid)
                    count += 1

        return count

    def dfs(self, i: int, j: int, grid: List[List[str]]):
        if i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= len(grid) or j >= len(grid[0]) or grid[i][j] != '1':
            return

        grid[i][j] = '#'

        self.dfs(i + 1, j, grid)
        self.dfs(i - 1, j, grid)
        self.dfs(i, j - 1, grid)
        self.dfs(i, j + 1, grid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in solution #2 you pass integer `ans` to the `dfs` function, the function may change it but this change is not seen by the caller because integer is immutable so the modified ans is a new object that has nothing to do with the original `ans=0`.

On the other hand, Solution #3, pass `List` which is mutable object. Changing (mutating) this object `grid[i][j] = '#'` is seen to any scope that hold (reference to) this object.

This is the same as Solution #1 which change `self.ans` which is again the very same attribute of the very same object in all the recursion scopes.